# Pandoc: What are the available syntax highlighters?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pandoc

Bullet point 18 of http://pandoc.org/demos.html#examples shows how to change the syntax highlighter used by giving an argument to `--highlight-style`.  For example:

```
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style pygments -o example18a.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style kate -o example18b.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style monochrome -o example18c.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style espresso -o example18d.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style haddock -o example18e.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style tango -o example18f.html
pandoc code.text -s --highlight-style zenburn -o example18g.html
```

I am wondering if these are the only color schemes available.  If not, how can I load a different syntax highlighter?  Can I define my own?

Comment: Editing the `.theme` file is now made easy with pandoc, cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47876166/2657549). This answer the " Can I define my own?" part of your question in the most pleasant way, I believe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Pandoc README says](http://pandoc.org/README.html):

> `--highlight-style=STYLE|FILE`
>
> Specifies the coloring style to be used in highlighted source code.
>   Options are `pygments` (the default), `kate`, `monochrome`,
>   `breezeDark`, `espresso`, `zenburn`, `haddock`, and `tango`.
>   For more information on syntax highlighting in pandoc, see
>   [Syntax highlighting](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting), below.  See also
>   `--list-highlight-styles`.
>
> Instead of a *STYLE* name, a JSON file with extension
>   `.theme` may be supplied.  This will be parsed as a KDE
>   syntax highlighting theme and (if valid) used as the
>   highlighting style.  To see a sample theme that can be
>   modified, `pandoc --print-default-data-file default.theme`.

The library [skylighting](https://github.com/jgm/skylighting) (in older versions [highlighting-kate](https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate)) is used for the highlighting. If you don't like any of the provided color schemes, you can either:

- Specify a `.theme` file as mentioned above,
- when exporting to HTML, `<span>` tags are generated that you can style with your custom CSS, or
- when exporting to LaTeX/PDF, you need to use a custom Pandoc LaTeX [template](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) and replace the `$highlighting-macros$` part with your custom color definitions, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2178).

Answer (score 46):

Since [pandoc 2.0.5](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.0.5), you can also use `--print-highlight-style` to output a `theme` file and edit it.

To me, the best way to use this option is to

1. Pick a pleasant available style
2. Output its `theme` file
3. Edit the `theme` file
4. Use it!

## 1. Available Styles

Pick your style, among the one already existing:

[image: breezedark]

[image: monochrome]

[image: kate]

[image: zenburn]

[image: espresso]

[image: haddock]

[image: tango]

## 2. Output its `theme` file

Once you decided which style was the closest to your needs, you can output its `theme` file, using (for instance for `pygments`, the default style):

```
pandoc --print-highlight-style pygments
```

so that you can store this style in a file, using, e.g.,

```
pandoc --print-highlight-style pygments > my_style.theme
```

With some shells, especially on Windows, using redirected output can lead to encoding problems. If that happens, use this instead:

```
pandoc -o my_style.theme --print-highlight-style pygments
```

## 3. Edit the file

Using the [Skylighting JSON Themes](https://github.com/tajmone/pandoc-goodies/tree/master/skylighting/themes) guide, edit the file according to your need / taste.

## 4. Use the file

In the right folder, just use

```
pandoc my_file.md --highlight-style my_style.theme -o doc.html
```

Comment: This is a godsend. I've been looking for something like this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Clément! I was unaware of this new feature until now. +1 from me!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67335392/2657549

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @tarleb, I just noticed them, and they really improved my answer!

Answer (score 29):

If your `pandoc --version` indicates a release of `1.15.1` (from Oct 15, 2015) or newer, then you can check if the `--bash-completion` parameter works for you to get a full list of available built-in highlighting styles.

Run

```
pandoc --bash-completion
```

If it works, you'll see a lot of output. And it will be useful well beyond the original question above...

If `--bash-completion` works, then put this line towards the end of your `${HOME}/.bashrc` file (on Mac OS X or Linux -- doesn't work on Windows yet):

```bash
eval "$(pandoc --bash-completion)"
```

Once you open a new terminal, you can use the `pandoc` command with *"tab completion"*:

```
pandoc --h[tab]
```

will yield

```
--help     --highlight-style  --html-q-tags

pandoc --hi[tab]
```

will yield

```
pandoc --highlight-style
```

### Answer to original question:

Now punch the `[tab]` key one more time, and you'll see

```
espresso   haddock   kate   monochrome  pygments    tango    zenburn
```

It's the list of all available syntax highlighters. To shorten the precedure, you could also type

```
pandoc --hi[tab][tab]
```

to get the same result.

### Usefulness of Pandoc's tab completion beyond original question:

Pandoc's bash tab completion also works for all other commandline switches:

```
pandoc -h[tab]
```

yields this -- a list of all possible command line parameters:

```
Display all 108 possibilities? (y or n)
--ascii                    --indented-code-classes    --template
--asciimathml              --jsmath                   --title-prefix
--atx-headers              --katex                    --to
--base-header-level        --katex-stylesheet         --toc
--bash-completion          --latex-engine             --toc-depth
--biblatex                 --latex-engine-opt         --trace
--bibliography             --latexmathml              --track-changes
--chapters                 --listings                 --variable
--citation-abbreviations   --mathjax                  --verbose
--columns                  --mathml                   --version
--csl                      --metadata                 --webtex
--css                      --mimetex                  --wrap
--data-dir                 --natbib                   --write
--default-image-extension  --no-highlight             -A
--dpi                      --no-tex-ligatures         -B
--dump-args                --no-wrap                  -D
--email-obfuscation        --normalize                -F
--epub-chapter-level       --number-offset            -H
--epub-cover-image         --number-sections          -M
--epub-embed-font          --old-dashes               -N
--epub-metadata            --output                   -R
--epub-stylesheet          --parse-raw                -S
--extract-media            --preserve-tabs            -T
--file-scope               --print-default-data-file  -V
--filter                   --print-default-template   -c
--from                     --read                     -f
--gladtex                  --reference-docx           -h
--help                     --reference-links          -i
--highlight-style          --reference-odt            -m
--html-q-tags              --section-divs             -o
--id-prefix                --self-contained           -p
--ignore-args              --slide-level              -r
--include-after-body       --smart                    -s
--include-before-body      --standalone               -t
--include-in-header        --tab-stop                 -v
--incremental              --table-of-contents        -w
```

One interesting use case for Pandoc's tab completion is this:

```
pandoc --print-default-d[tab][tab]
```

gives the output list of completion for `pandoc --print-default-data-file`. This list gives you a uniq insight into what data files your instance of Pandoc will load when it is doing its work. For example you could investigate a detail of Pandoc's default ODT (OpenDocument Text file) output styling like this:

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file odt/content.xml \
 | tr " " "\n" \
 | tr "<" "\n" \
 | grep --color "style"
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Pandoc version 1.18 (released in October 2016) or later, a new answer is possible:

```
  pandoc --list-highlight-languages
```

and

```
  pandoc --list-highlight-styles
```

will give you all the info you were asking for.

Other new informational command line parameters added to v1.18 are:

```
  pandoc --list-input-formats
  pandoc --list-output-formats
  pandoc --list-extensions
```