# How to set knitr syntax highlighting themes in R Notebooks?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, rnotebook, knitrbootstrap

I'm trying to get one of the knitr highlight themes applied to my R Notebook, but what I'm doing doesn't work (in both the Notebook Preview and the Knitted HTML file.)

Can you explain to me what the proper way to do this is?

Thanks!

````
  ---
    output:
      html_notebook: 
        code_folding: none
        df_print: kable
        theme: yeti
        toc: yes
        toc_depth: 4
      html_document:
        df_print: kable
    ---


        ```{r}
        library(knitr)
        thm = knit_theme$get("molokai")  # parse the theme to a list
        knit_theme$set(thm)
        ```
````

Message when running command in R Notebook.
[image: Message when running command in R Notebook.]

What the knitted html loks like.
[image]

Comment: You can set the highlighting theme in your YAML header with `highlight: espresso`.

Comment: That way of doing it seems to be limited to the 6 or so highlighting themes offered by default, and not the extended selection included in knitr.

Comment: This is set by pandoc. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30880200/7347699